# How to put datetime from model to the EditorFor in the EditView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, data-binding

My edit field looks like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastService, "date")
```

And when I'm trying to edit model, datetime fields in the view are empty. 
But it displays correct in the details view.

Text and int fields shows correct data in the Edit views.

How can I fill datetime fields with data from model in Edits?

Comment: you need to display datepicker?

Comment: @SivaRajini Yes.. In the webkit it displays even without "date" parameter.

Comment: You'll need to create an EditorTemplate in your Views\Shared\EditorTemplate folder. Name it DateTime.cshtml

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx#demo